# Nginx gives "permission denied" when proxying Gunicorn on CentOS

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

I want use Nginx and Gunicorn to deploy my Flask app on CentOS 7. However, I get a "Permission denied" error when using the following Nginx config.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.org;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

```
2017/05/07 18:01:43 [crit] 9470#0: *1 connect() to 127.0.0.1:8000 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.1.59, server: example.org, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico", host: "example.org", referrer: "http://example.org/"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by selinux configration,simply disable selinx would solve the issue.

```
# sestatus -v
SELinux status:                 enabled

# setenforce 0

# sestatus -v
SELinux status:                 disabled
```